# flex swallow or trap error once identified without triggering debug popup

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I am wondering if it is possible to swallow or trap an error in flex once it has been identified.

For example using the following code I can trace the error no problem, but when using a debug air player the popup window opens with a dialog. I would prefer to just swallow the error and not disclose it publicly as I know it is there and causes no harm. this means not adjusting mm.cfg locally.

> [trace] error Type 2 [ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2
>   text="Load error." errorID=3228]
>
> [trace] swallow error?

using the following code

```
loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(
                    UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, catcherr);

private function catcherr(event:UncaughtErrorEvent):void {
            if (event.error is Error)
            {
                var error:Error = event.error as Error;
                trace("error Type 1");
            }
            else if (event.error is ErrorEvent)
            {
                var errorEvent:ErrorEvent = event.error as ErrorEvent;
                trace("error Type2 " + errorEvent);
                if (errorEvent.text="Load Error.")
                {
                    trace("swallow error?");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                // a non-Error, non-ErrorEvent type was thrown and uncaught
                trace("error Type 3");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/UncaughtErrorEvent.html) says:

> When content is running in a debugger version of the runtime, such as
>   the debugger version of Flash Player or the AIR Debug Launcher (ADL),
>   an uncaught error dialog appears when an uncaught error happens. For
>   those runtime versions, the error dialog appears even when a listener
>   is registered for the uncaughtError event. To prevent the dialog from
>   appearing in that situation, call the UncaughtErrorEvent object's
>   **`preventDefault()`** method.